# How to restrict or block mail with embedded images being automatically displayed in Outlook 2016?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I'm getting a few emails that bypassed the spam filters and while I have the automatic downloading of images disabled, these e-mails display inappropriate pictures using embedded images.

Viewing the source displays something like this where the offending image is displayed:

`<img src="cid:xxx.xxxxxxxxx@random-spam-domain-dot-com" height="400" width="600">`

While the messages are annoying and easy enough to delete, my biggest concern is the automatic display of these inappropriate images.  Is there a way to block embedded images from displaying automatically?  Is it possible to create a rule where HTML emails that contain `src="cid:` be forced into plain text?

Answer (score 0):

When you have outlook open go to **File**

Choose **options**

Select **Trust Center**

Under Microsoft Outlook Trust Center, click **Trust Center Settings**.

**Check** the **Don't download pictures automatically in HTML e-mail messages or RSS items** check box.

Comment: This only works to stop displaying images that are externally hosted.  It doesn't stop Outlook from displaying images that are embedded in the e-mail.

Comment: The only way to do so would be to go to the trust center, then the tab 'Email Security' and then Select 'All default messages as text without layout'  or something like that.. My outlook is in Dutch, couldnt find the exact translation online. this however will remove any visual things, it'll be plain text, No images, No bold text, No letter types etc

Comment: The sad thing about this feature is that it does it with EVERY e-mail, including ones from trusted senders, which would be extremely disruptive to handle a small handful of spam e-mails.  Even when I deem an e-mail as safe, it converts it back to plain text the moment I navigate off of it.